# Find files whose content match a line from text file

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find

I have a text file - `accessions.txt` (below is a subset of this file):

```
KRO94967.1
KRO95967.1
KRO96427.1
KRO94221.1
KRO94121.1
KRO94145.1
WP_088442850.1
WP_088252850.1
WP_088643726.1
WP_088739685.1
WP_088283155.1
WP_088939404.1
```

And I have a directory with multiple files (`*.align`).

I want to find the filenames (`*.align`) which content matches any line within my `accessions.txt` text file.

I know that `find . -exec grep -H 'STRING' {} +` works to find specific strings (e.g replacing STRING with `WP_088939404.1` returns every filename where the string `WP_088939404.1` is present).

Is there a way to replace `STRING` with "all strings inside my text file" ?

Or

Is there another (better) way to do this?

I was trying to avoid writing a loop that reads the content of all my files as there are too many of them.

Many thanks!

Comment: There's not an easier way other than looping - you could try and parse for string1 \| string2 etc. where \| means 'or' but another thing you could do is to use grep -m1  which will mean it will 'stop' search as soon as it's found a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for grep's -f option.

```
find . -name '*.align' -exec grep -Fxqf accessions.txt {} \; -print
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` can take a list of patterns to match with `-f`.

```
grep -lFf accessions.txt directory/*.align
```

`-F` tells grep to interpret the lines as fixed strings, not regex patterns.

Sometimes, `-w` is also needed to prevent matching inside words, e.g.

```
abcd
```

might match not only `abcd`, but also `xabcd` or `abcdy`. Sometimes, preprocessing the input list is needed to prevent unwanted matching if the rules are more complex.